# Обход рекурсии .click()

Tags: jquery, рекурсия

Допустим есть такой код:

```
<div class="click-block">
    <div class="click">
        <div class="clickone">click me</div>
    </div>

    <div class="clicktwo"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('.click-block .click').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('.clickone').click();
    $(this).closest('.click-block').find('.clicktwo').click();
});
</script>
```

И вот из-за того, что "клик" находится в обработчике "клика" в консоли показывается:
`too much recursion`

Это лечиться? И как?

Comment: лечится добавлением запрета всплытия в обработчике clickone: `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @Grundy, а можно поподробнее? Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `.click` нажался `.clickone` и `.clicktwo`.

Comment: что происходит в обработчике clickone?

Comment: @Grundy, эм.. Тут `$(this).find('.clickone').click();`? - ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае нужно изменить подход, иначе клик в `.clickone` вызовет `.click`, который вызовет `.clickone`, который...
Остановить через `e.stopPropagation` не выйдет, т. к. если остановить в `.clickone`, на котором идёт вызов, то до `.click` события банально не дойдёт.

Максимум - вынести `.click` за пределы `.clickone` и остановить всплытие.
Но если кто-то промахнётся - сломается код, поэтому измените структуру `html`.

```js
$('.clickone').on('click', e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.info('Click on ".clickone"');
});
$('.clicktwo').on('click', e => {
  console.info('Click on ".clicktwo"');
});
$('.click-block .click').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.clickone').click();
  $(this).closest('.click-block').find('.clicktwo').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click-block">
  <div class="click">
    Run both
    <div class="clickone">Evil zone</div>
  </div>
  

  <div class="clicktwo"></div>
</div>
```